# filtering Tables and put it into an array , some new in Xcode 7?

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

I've got `Xcode 7` but since there are many errors in my old Project,
I stuck with one Problem:

**xcode 6:**

```
var myData: Array<Row> = []
var my_mData: Array<Row> = []

var m_mitglieder : Query!
var m_firmen : Query!
var stmt_m : Query!
var stmt_f : Query!
var Daten:[String] = []

let m_vorname = Expression<String>("Vorname")
.....
```

**in ViewDidLoad**

```
m_mitglieder = dbFirma["Mitglieder]
stmt = m_mitglieder.select(m_vorname,m_nb......).filter(mnr0 == m_mnr)
myData = Array(stmt)

if Int(myData[0].get(m_nb)) > 0 {
  Daten.append(myData[0].get(m_nb))
}
...
```

**xcode 7:**

```
var myData: Array<Row> = []
var my_mData: Array<Row> = []

let m_mitglieder = Table("Mitglieder")
let m_firmen = Table("firmen")
//var stmt_m : Query!
//var stmt_f : Query!

let m_vorname = Expression<String>("Vorname")
.....
```

**in ViewDidLoad**

```
m_mitglieder = dbFirma["Mitglieder]
let stmt = m_mitglieder.select(m_vorname,m_nb......).filter(mnr0 == m_mnr)
let myData = Array(stmt)  <<<<<ERROR Missing Argument lable 'arrayLiteral:' in call

if Int(myData[0].get(m_nb)) > 0 {
  Daten.append(myData[0].get(m_nb))
}
...
```

I get the error message :  `Missing Argument lable 'arrayLiteral:' in call`

But when I try to fix it to

```
myData = Array(arrayLiteral: stmt)
```

then I get errors as

```
Daten.append(myData[0].get(m_nb))  <<<ERROR: Value of type
'ScaleQuerystring>' has no member 'get'
```

How can I fix this Problem?

Comment: This is really strange syntax. You should read the Apple Swift ebook (again).

Comment: At least there is a missing double quote in `dbFirma["Mitglieder]`